# Running query multiple times with different parameter

Tags: oracle, for-loop, cursor

I would like to run the query within a loop.There are two tables and I would like to take id from one table and add new rows to the other table with new value added for each id.

I have two tables as below:

Profile table:

````
ID  NAME    VALUE
1   AAA 111
2   BBB 222
3   CCC 333
4   DDD 444 ```
````

Attribute table:

```
ID  ATTRIBUTE_ID    VALUE
1       1            VAL1
2       1            VAL2
3       2            VAL2
4       2            VAL3
```

Now I want to take each unique ID from profile table and insert a respective row in Attribute table with new value. The end table should look like this:

```
ID  ATTRIBUTE_ID    VALUE
1       1            VAL1
2       1            VAL2
3       2            VAL2
4       2            VAL3
5       1            VAL4
6       2            VAL4
```

I have tried following cursor and failed:

```
DECLARE
-- Store the SELECT query in a cursor
  CURSOR l_cur IS SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM PROFILE table;  
--Create a variable that will hold each result from the cursor
l_cur_rec l_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
-- Open the Cursor so that we may retrieve results
  OPEN l_cur;  
  LOOP
-- INSERT INTO another table
        INSERT INTO ATTRIBUTE table (ID, ATTRIBUTE_ID, PLATFORM_ID) 
        VALUES((select max(ID)+1 from ATTRIBUTE_PLATFORM), (l_cur) , VAL4);  
-- EXIT the loop if there are no more results
    EXIT WHEN l_cur%NOTFOUND;     
  END LOOP;
-- Close the cursor to release the memory
  CLOSE l_cur;
END;
```

Comment: What happened to other 2 rows from profile table? How did 4 + 4 become 6 rows?

Comment: What are the actual names of your tables? `INSERT INTO ATTRIBUTE table` isn't going to work - the word `table` is not in a place where it's syntactically correct.  ???

Comment: *"I have tried following cursor and failed:"* Is this literally the code you're running? If so, have you tried fixing the syntax errors?

Comment: This is purely an example I typed. I understand there are errors. But, I thought people here are self sufficient to grasp the problem and suggest a solution like the one below.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sequence and trigger to fill `id` in attribute table, or in Oracle 12 you can use auto genereated column. `select max(id)+1` is not a good idea in real tables, because of concurent sessions. Then you can make insert in one statement:

```
insert into attribute_table (attribute_id, value) 
  select distinct id, 'VAL4' from profile_table
```

If you want to stay at your solution then correct your code like here:

```
declare
  cursor l_cur is select distinct(id) from profile_table;  
  l_cur_rec l_cur%rowtype;
begin
  open l_cur;  
  loop
    fetch l_cur into l_cur_rec;
    exit when l_cur%notfound;     
    dbms_output.put_line(l_cur_rec.id);
    insert into attribute_table (id, attribute_id, value) 
      values((select max(id)+1 from attribute_table), l_cur_rec.id, 'VAL4');  
  end loop;
  close l_cur;
end;
```